# Do I need to create a hosted zone in Route 53 for each domain even if all domains point to same EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I was wondering if it's necessary to create multiple hosted zones for each domain or can I just use one hosted zone for all domains and simply change the A record for each.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a hosted zone for each top-level domain (TLD). So, if you have domain1.com and domain2.com, you'll need 2 hosted zones. However, if you have subdomains: domain1.com and sub.domain1.com, you could combine those. Externally, you'll need a zone for each base domain.

Comment: Yes they're all TLD so I guess I do need a hosted zone for each...thanks!

Comment: The answer is correct, but there's a terminology error.  `.com` is a top-level domain (TLD).  `example.com` is properly called a [second-level domain (SLD)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain).